# React Native Maps library

Tags: android, react-native, maps

I have problems with installing react native maps library, when I type:

```
npm install react-native-maps --save
```

error shows:

react-native-maps error
[image]

dependencies:

```
"react": "15.3.2",  
"react-native": "0.36.0"
```

Comment: sometimes the version of root system (sudo) version is different from the user. I have been struggling with this problem almost a week

Comment: In wich path you are trying to install this one. And can you go to /android and do "gradlew.bat clean" ?

Comment: Can you please share your package.json file? What is the React and React native version mention there? I am also working on map in react native and we are also using same lib. Share some more details so that I can help you.

Answer (score 5):

As Rishabh says, you should upgrade to the latest versions of react, react-native and react-native-maps.

Depending on how complex your project is, I often find the easiest way to upgrade is to create a brand new, clean project:

```
react-native init MyProjectName
```

and then install react-native maps (and another other dependencies)

```
npm install --save react-native-maps
react-native link
```

and then copy across all your Javascript source code into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade it to following dependency

```
"react": "15.4.1",
"react-native": "^0.39.0"
```

To upgrade react native to newest version you can follow offical doc. I have used "Alternative" section mention in [React native blog.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html)

After upgrade your react native follow below steps:

1. Install react native map using following command ***npm install
   react-native-maps --save*** ([for reference](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps))
2. Use command ***react-native link*** to link react-native-maps resource with project
3. After linking to project make sure it's linked properly by checking at following files
4. Go to android/app/build.gradle  and check following entry is there or not

   dependencies {
         **compile project(':react-native-maps')**
         compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
         compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
         compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    }
5. in android/settings.gradle react-native-maps project should be included

   ```
   include ':react-native-maps'
   project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
   ```
6. In android/app/src/main/java/com//MainApplication.java react-native-maps package should be registered.

   ```
   import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
    ...
   @Override
   protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
       return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
               new MainReactPackage(),
               new MapsPackage()
       );
   }
   ```
7. go to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml add following under application tag.

Let me know if you still get error. Please share the important code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should first upgrade react and react native .If you are building app from scratch then go with

"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "^0.41.0"
then install "npm i react-native-maps --save "

then use the docs from https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps to setup the map modules in native component .
before starting the app do react-native link .

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to the latest versions of react, react-native and react-native-maps.

```
npm install --save react-native-maps
(or Yarn add react-native-maps)
react-native link
```

make sure react-native verion upgrade

You can see my demo project on github
https://github.com/krishna201/react-native-maps/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

It is very complicated. I myself had trouble.

First update SDKs using Android Studio (In Case of Android).

Create a RN project. Open project using Android Studio / Eclipse with android folder in the RN project director.

Update the gradle version of the project.

Refer here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0P87WblPKU

Update the build.gradle files both in app specific and project specific so that
it uses implementation.

Then install react-native-maps. Manually update the android and iOS native files as they instructed. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the yarn for dependency management. you can easily install on your system follow https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install.

simple use

```
yarn add react-native-maps
```